# OpenLdap 2.4 ACL

Tags: openldap

Can you help me with rights for group OpenLdap 2.4?

There is my `slapd.conf`

```
# Allow LDAPv2 client connections.  This is NOT the default.
allow bind_v2

#Basic rights for authentication
access to attrs=userPassword
        by self write
        by anonymous auth
        by * none

#Rights for groups GR_READ and GR_WRITE
access to *
      by self write
      by group.exact="cn=GR_READ,ou=groups,ou=BGA,o=Company,c=com" read
      by group.exact="cn=GR_WRITE,ou=groups,ou=BGA,o=Company,c=com" write
      by * none
```

This configuration work fine. I have people in groups with name GR_READ and GR_WRITE

But my problem is with synchronize DIT between two Openldap DB. 
Synchronization do not work! I recieved error findbase failed! 32 in slapd.log
I have Multi-master configuration.

If I change configuration slapd.conf to this:

```
#Basic rights for authentication
access to attrs=userPassword
        by self write
        by anonymous auth
        by * none

#Rights for groups GR_READ and GR_WRITE
access to *
        by * read
```

Synchronization works! No errors in slapd.log. But I do not have a rights to my groups and anonymous user can bind LDAP.

Then I have another problem with disable anonymous.
If I change

```
# Allow LDAPv2 client connections.  This is NOT the default.
allow bind_v2
```

TO

```
disallow bind_anon
```

Synchronization do not work! I recieved error findbase failed! 32 in slapd.log

Thanks for help.